# Geting the curent status of the cycles viewport Render with the Python API

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Is it possible to find out if a cycles viewport Rendering is done using the Python API? It is displayed on the top left corner of the 3D viewport, so the information has to be somewhere, but I can't find a way to access it.

[image]

I can use the View3DOverlay Class to turn the Visibility on and off but I can't get access to what is inside.
If there is no other way I would be fine with a solution that allows me to read the GPU buffer of that section or something similar, that allows me to use text recognition.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once! If the answer wasn't what you want or you want to add extra information, edit your original question or comment to the answer that was given by moonboots: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302993/geting-the-curent-status-of-the-cycles-viewport-render.